How to read descriptor from I2C HID device
I'm trying to interface with a touchpad that uses HID over I2C. I can successfully read reports from address 0x00 but I can't figure out how to read the device descriptor. I came across this hack a day article is that claims you can read the descriptor from 0x20 however this doesn't seem to work for me all I get back are zeros.
How do I read the descriptor from an HID over I2C?

We don't know how you are currently trying to read the descriptor. Maybe there is some bug in your code. It should be readable from register 0x20. Maybe post your code or scope or logic analyzer traces of the I2C bus.
